# File delta encoding library for C?

Tags: library, c

I'm looking for a library that allows you to create a delta encoding of file changes whenever a file is changed within a directory. I'm trying to use this for a file synchronization app written in C. Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Could you provide us some information as to how you want to get that information presented to you? Are you looking for text files, binaries or both? Currently your question is a bit thin and experience says that more detailed questions get better answers.